# how to dismiss the skscene for back button functionality in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to implement the back button functionality in the sprite kit. Is there a way to dismiss the view.?  It may sound stupid but I am new to sprite kit. Help me!!

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried till now. What problem are you facing? What is 'back button functionality'? Where do you want to put it?

Comment: Do you need to go to a new scene? Or perhaps dismiss the current view controller and return to another view controller? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to change scene between `SKScene`s try to use:

```
[self.view presentScene:SceneThatYouWantShow];
```